# Can I create an SFTP account that has access to all chrooted directories?

Tags: ssh, sftp

We have school districts that SFTP us student info which we process and load into another app. The system we have been using is dated and under another dept's purview. I have set up a chrooted SFTP account for each school district on one of my RHEL servers. How can I set up an SFTP account that can access the files in all those directories? I need to pull all the files to another server to process them.

This is what I currently have in my sshd_config:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match Group sftpusers
      ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u
```

I don't know a lot about the interworkings of SSH/SFTP so please be gentle. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything unless you've configured the server to only allow logins from members of the stpusers group
From [the manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html)...

> **Match**   Introduces a conditional block.  If all of the criteria on
> the Match line are satisfied, the keywords on the following
> lines override those set in the global section of the
> config file, until either another Match line or the end of
> the file.  If a keyword appears in multiple Match blocks
> that are satisfied, only the first instance of the keyword
> is applied.

If you **do** have a line like....

```
AllowGroups sftpusers
```

Simply add another group referencing the users whomshould have unconstrained access....

```
AllowGroups sftpusers,wheel
```

Note that although I have provided a link to web page on the internet, you should always check the local man page on your host for how to configure the software correctly.

Comment: I don't have an AllowGroups line and I tried many permutations but I couldn't get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentation, this ended up working:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match Group sftpusers
      ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u
Match Group administrator
      AllowUsers *
```